# Handle a Message

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-handler

I have question about handler a [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html). Anybody know how to retreieve the data from a message? Currently I have a method called handleMessage

```
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message message) {

 Bundle bundle = message.getData();
 String text = message.obtain().toString();
```

If I run the debug mode, the message contain:
[image]

I would like to get the object (which means "www.google.com") and put it as a string. Anybody know how to get it? I tried with `message.obtain.toString`, it doesn't succeed.

Thanks

Comment: Try with `message.getData().get("text");` or `message.toString();` if any of them works.

Comment: your message.obj is a `Result` object, so you should cast it to `Result` and access `text` field

Answer (score 1):

`Message.obtain()` returns an empty message from the pool. What your are looking for is in `obj`.

```
   String text = (String) message.obj;
```

`message.obj` is an `Object`, so it has to be casted to the exacted type

Answer (score 0):

Set the data to the Message.obj first, then you can get from the obj.

Answer (score -1):

To set data in message

```
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = "do";
        msg.what = 1;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

To fetch data from message

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        if(message.what == 1){
            String value = (String) message.obj;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```